# Sending a reply to a specific message in a Gmail thread using GmailApp in Google Apps Script and quoting the original message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, reply

I am working on a Google Apps Script project where I need to send a reply to a specific message within a **Gmail thread** using the GmailApp service. However, I have encountered a couple of challenges that I'm seeking assistance with.

Firstly, I want to send the reply to the recipient of the first message in the thread, which was originally sent by me. I have tried using the **GmailApp** service, but it only sends the reply to the sender (me) by default. I am wondering if there is a way to write a snippet code to send the reply to the recipient instead, allowing me to send a follow-up reminder.
I have the thread ID and will recall the reply email body from another sheet cell in Google Sheets.
Secondly, I need to preserve the formatting of the reply email body, which is stored in a cell of another sheet. The body contains multiple paragraphs, and I want to avoid merging the lines of the email body and preserve the font size. I am unsure of the best approach to achieve this using GmailApp. Should I consider using HTML body or explore alternative methods?

Furthermore, I would like to quote the original message within the reply email, similar to how Gmail UI quotes the original message in a reply. Specifically, I want to include the original message below the email body of the reply, showing the sender, date, and the original message content. For example, something like:

> "On Fri, Jun 23, 2023 at 4:32 PM Hamed XXXXXX@gmail.com wrote:
>
> Dear--------,
>
> I hope this email finds you well."

I would appreciate any guidance to address these challenges and achieve the desired functionality within my Google Apps Script project.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion:

> Note: This may not totally resolve your problem because you haven't included your data, but it will serve as a starting point and guidance in doing so.

The script below works as follows

1. Retrieves the recipient of the first message on the thread using the `GmailApp` service
2. Retrieve the first message body on the thread sent by you
3. Extract the reply email body from a `sample sheet` I made with a `sample paragraph` using `SpreadSheetApp` Service
4. Quoting the first message body similar to how Gmail UI quotes the original message in a reply
5. Send the email to the recipient

### Script:

```
function sendReplyToThread() {

  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 11)[0]; //Get the first thread on your inbox
  var threadById = GmailApp.getThreadById(firstThread.getId()); //Get the ID of the thread
  var messages = threadById.getMessages();
  var firstMessage = messages[0]
  var firstEmail = firstMessage.getBody(); //The first message of the thread sent by you
  var recipient = firstMessage.getTo() // Email of the first recipient

  // Getting the reply email body from sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var data = data.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");   // Replace line breaks with HTML line break tags
  var emailBody = "<html><body>" + data + "</body></html>"

  // Obtaining and quoting the original message
  var originalMessage = '<div style="border-left: 1px solid #ccc; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">';
  originalMessage += '<p style="color: rgb(80, 0, 80);">On ' + formatDate(firstMessage.getDate()) + ' <a href="mailto:' + firstMessage.getFrom() + '">' + firstMessage.getFrom() + '</a> wrote:</p>';
  originalMessage += '<blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 10px; border-left: 1px solid rgb(80, 0, 80); padding-left: 10px; color: rgb(80, 0, 80);">' + firstEmail + '</blockquote>';
  originalMessage += '</div>';

  //Sending the reply email
  var replyDraft = firstThread.reply("", {
    htmlBody: emailBody + "<br><br>" + originalMessage
    , replyTo: recipient});
}
//Function for date format
function formatDate(date) {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "EEE, MMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
  return formattedDate;
}
```

### Sample Thread:

[image]

### Reply Email using the script:

[image]

### References:

[Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getthreadbyidid)

[GetTo method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getto)

[CreateDraft method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createdraftrecipient,-subject,-body)

[reply method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replybody,-options)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. But, there are two issues. First, although you used HTML codes, the final result merges all lines of emailbody together and turns it into a single paragraph. It also occurs for the original message too. Secondly, as it creates a new draft instead of using reply codes, some email services interpret and consider the reply email as a new and separate email from the thread. I tried your code and although Yahoo considered it in the thread gmail considered it as a new email in my sent box.

Comment: What is your opinion about using reply codes such as `Gmailapp.thread.reply`? I already used it and it supports htmlbody and properly sends the reply within a thread. But the issue is that it only sends the reply to the sender of the email. I do not know how to modify it in order to send it to the recipient instead of the sender

Comment: I apologize if I misunderstood your question, I have updated my answer above that uses `Gmail.thread.reply` with the advance parameter `replyTo` to send the reply to the intended recipient. As for the html body, it would be best if you can share a dummy sheet for me to work on the html part.

Comment: Thank you for your modification. It works fine for sending a reply to the first message of the thread but the paragraph formatting issue remains. I mean it does not preserve paragraph formatting and merges all of the lines together, although you have used htmlbody codes.  [This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/122DX0kkLrD7a1A3ewwlOwDA9Ft8FHLj93RbvaQ-c-sk/edit?usp=sharing) is an example of my input data for email body text:

Comment: in addition, do you know how can we modify the code in order to show our Name and Last Name for the recipient?
I know that in Gmail API we can use '`From: ${firstName} ${lastName} <${senderEmail}>\n`,' but in GmailApp I dont know how can we do that

Comment: I am glad the reply to the first message on the thread works! I have updated my answer above for the paragraph formatting issue.

Comment: Thank you @George. You are awesome! **Now it works properly**. In your opinion is it reliable to use `<p style="font-size: ; "> ` for changing the font size of emailbody or using `<font size="3"> ` ?  which one is reliable for being interpreted in most of the email platforms?  In addition, I know that in Gmail API we can use `From: ${firstName} ${lastName} <${senderEmail}>\n` in order to add the Name and Last Name of sender , can we do the same in GmailApp?

Comment: After multiple tries, I discovered another issue with the script. It considers the recipient's email address for `To:` and `Reply-To:` in the header so when the recipient wants to reply to our message, it recognizes the recipient's email address for the `To:`  field, and in other words, he sends the reply to himself! While this was not the issue in Gmail API

Comment: in addition I do not know why it sends the reply to me whenever I use apps script trigger for running the code. But it works find when I run the code manually